# How to make sure javascript and css is cached in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, cache-control

I am reasonably new to angular (5), and have noticed that the javascript files (vendor.bundle, main.bundle, etc) are being reloaded each time I visit a page.

Is there anything in particular I should be doing to make sure that these are held in  a browser cache after the first time they are loaded?

I guess I would need to add a **cache-control** header, but am not sure where to put it in the code, or whether this is something that the Angular-Cli could generate

Comment: If you build you app for production, it will use the browsers default cache.

If you are using the live development server, it reloads every time, as it should as you are making constant changes to it.

Comment: Well the build adds a hash to the filename, which should invalidate any caching issues, but my problem is that the files do not appear to be being cached at all whether built in prod or dev modes

Comment: I think it is completely up to your browser's options. Are you sure your browser is not set to ignore caches?
One other thing I found is disabling output hashing (`--output-hashing`) (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)  which can provide the same results, maybe you are using a build tool that calls it when building?

Comment: No, output hashing is enabled, and I think my browser setup is pretty normal

Comment: how did you make sure the browser is not using the cached version?

Comment: In the network tab in Chrome in the size column, it should say something like (from Disk Cache)

Comment: Did you make sure to uncheck "Disable cache" from that tab ?

Comment: @jazza1000. Hello, have you found solution for this?

Comment: @user233428 - sorry no, I haven't

Comment: @jazza1000, If it's relevant now I think I've found a solution https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/workbox-lab/#0

Answer (score 2):

Angular have lib called [Service workers](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started), which simply can be installed in cli project by below cli command

```
      ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*
```

Note: project name can be obtained from angular.json

This command do the most required configuration but still some other stuff is needed, Which can be found on the flowing link [service-worker confi.](https://alligator.io/angular/service-workers/) but some of this configuration already done by previous mentioned command. but also more configuration may be needed in "ngsw-config.json" file.

**But unfortunately** i tested this inside spring war and still the big files still downloaded every time **without any caching** but if i deployed on http server direct it work perfect.

[Inside Spring War Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0gdS.png)

For More Info. Please Check the blob of [Angular Service Worker - Step-By-Step Guide for turning your Application into a PWA](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-service-worker/)

[image: Using NPM Http Server]